# After upgrading to latest angular response and requestOptions are not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have upgraded angular 4 to 7 but some of the things are not working like response, requestOptions etc
when i am importing them from @angular/http like when it was importing it in angular 4 it says deprecated.
importing from @angular/common/http is not working for me either

```
import {
 ConnectionBackend,
 Headers,
 Request,
 RequestOptions,
 RequestOptionsArgs,
 Response
 } from "@angular/http";
```

everything is deprecated.
how can i solve this any help?
thanks

Comment: Have a look at HttpClient, import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 1):

You should first check out the [Angular Migration guide](https://update.angular.io/), and for your case, select 4.0 to 7.0. Once you have done so, scroll down and take note of this section:

> Switch from HttpModule and the Http service to HttpClientModule and
>   the HttpClient service. HttpClient simplifies the default ergonomics
>   (You don't need to map to json anymore) and now supports typed return
>   values and interceptors

In addtion, the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated-code) has mentioned that too:

> http: deprecate @angular/http in favor of @angular/common/http
>   (#18906) (72c7b6e)

Therefore, you should be importing from `'@angular/common/http'` instead.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
.
.
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Comment: and what about  RequestOptions,
  RequestOptionsArgs,?

Comment: @usmansaleem you do not need them anymore. Let me include the example here

Comment: `this.http.post<string>(`${this.baseUrl}/get_data?user_id=${this.userId}`, requestBody, httpOptions)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142819/upgrading-from-angular-4-to-7-causing-some-problems 
can you please look at this post of mine