# upgrading from angular 4 to 7 causing some problems

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application

hey i have upgraded my project from angular 4 to angular 7 and some of the services, modules are deprecated.
this is my app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    StoreModule.forRoot({})
  ],
  providers: [
    SessionTimeoutService,
    SpinnerService,
    {
      provide: HttpClient,
      useFactory: httpFactory,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Store, SpinnerService]
    },
    UtilService,
    { provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: DateParserFormatter }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    ServiceLocatorService.injector = this.injector;
  }
}
```

now XHRBackend, RequestOptions are now deprecated and giving me error 
can someone tell me how to resolve it?

and this is my Http interceptor file

```js
@Injectable()
export class InterceptedHttp extends HttpClient {
  constructor(
    backend: HttpBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    private store: Store<any>,
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(
    url: string | HttpRequest,
    options?: RequestOptionsArgs
  ): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    this.showLoader();
    return this.tryCatch(super.request(url, options)).finally(() => {
      this.hideLoader();
    });
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
  }

  post(
    url: string,
    body: string,
    options?: RequestOptionsArgs
  ): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(
      super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options))
    );
  }

  put(
    url: string,
    body: string,
    options?: RequestOptionsArgs
  ): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(
      super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options))
    );
  }

  delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
  }

  patch(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    options?: RequestOptionsArgs
  ): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(
      super.patch(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options))
    );
  }

  private updateUrl(req: string) {
    return environment.origin + req;
  }

  private getRequestOptionArgs(
    options?: RequestOptionsArgs
  ): RequestOptionsArgs {
    if (options == null) {
      options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    if (options.headers == null) {
      options.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    }
    options.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    options.headers.append(
      "Authorization",
      ` Bearer ${sessionStorage.AccessToken}`
    );

    return options;
  }
}
```

i am getting errors 
  RequestOptions,
  RequestOptionsArgs,
these are deprecated now i am getting errors how to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequestOptions deprecated symbol error in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489115/requestoptions-deprecated-symbol-error-in-angular-5)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use new packge from @angular/common/http
like

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
```

So mostly you will use HttpHeaders to construct your ajax header like params formdata etc...

> Headers -> HttpHeaders
>
> Response -> HttpResponse
>
> RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs are remove and you have to use HttpParams

Please read new change log [here](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: HttpParams giving me errors 
throwing options and header error

Comment: What are you trying to complish ?

Comment: i want http interceptor to work like it was before but now it is giving me errors everywhere in file

Comment: first there is an error in super () saying expected 1 arg
and then every request is giving error saying Incompatible override for member from HttpClient 
and super.get super.put giving error

Comment: I think you should upload your source code somewhere so I can take a look